# GitHub Pages - including files from same repo

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

So, I have a repo on GitHub which is displaying a website via GitHub Pages. The publishing source is the `/docs/` subfolder on the `master` branch (and this is the only branch). I have some other JavaScript files in a `/src/` subfolder. So essentially, the project structure is something like:

```
/
 docs/
      index.html
 src/
     Main.js
     ... (other .js files) ...
 README.md
 ...
```

Now, I want `/docs/index.html` to be able to load and use `/src/Main.js`. On my local machine, this is easy enough - I can just reference it as

```
../src/Main.js
```

inside my `/docs/index.html` file.

However, when I try to view the live project on GitHub, there are problems. The live version of `/docs/index.html` file is now located at

```
https://(my-username).github.io/(my-repo-name)/
```

Therefore, it looks for `/src/Main.js` at

```
https://(my-username).github.io/src/Main.js
```

which returns a 404.

Actually, I don't even know where I can find the `/src/Main.js` file, as

```
https://(my-username).github.io/(my-repo-name)/src/Main.js
```

also returns a 404.

So, **how can I load the `/src/Main.js` file from my `/docs/index.html` file?** Ideally, I'd like a solution that will work both on my local machine, and on the live version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that GitHub Pages can only find files that are in the "publishing source". Therefore, if you have the publishing source set to `/docs/`, it  won't be able to access files outside the `/docs/` folder.

So, the solution is to set the publishing source to root `/`, move `index.html` to root, and then you can access all subdirectories of the root (including the `/src/` subfolder).